# How can i pass a function of return type Future<Dynamic> without it being executed before i decide to do so in dart

Tags: function, flutter, dart, arguments

I have created a dialogue box in my flutter app and i want it to be reusable. So each time i call it i pass in two arguments, the text to be displayed to the user and the function to be executed if they confirm the action. here is the code

**The dialogue widget**

```
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 30.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                        child: Text(

                            //The text argument is passed here

                          widget.text,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                      )),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: ButtonTheme(
                                height: 35.0,
                                minWidth: 110.0,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  shape: buttonShapeDeco,
                                  splashColor: Colors.black.withAlpha(40),
                                  child: Text(
                                    widget.button,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 13.0),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: ()async{

                                  //I expect the passed function to be executed here after the user confirms the action
                                    await widget.action;

                                    }
                                  },
                                )),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 20.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                              child:  ButtonTheme(
                                  height: 35.0,
                                  minWidth: 110.0,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    shape: buttonShapeDeco,
                                    splashColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(40),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Cancel',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 13.0),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    });
                                    },
                                  ))
                          ),
                        ],
                      ))
                ],
              )),
```

In my instance 'm trying to sign out a user only after they press the confirm button to logout.

**Here is the code**

```
                    onTap: ()async{
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (_) => Dialogue(text: 'Are you sure you want to logout?',button: 'Logout',action: _auth.signOut(),pop:true),
                      );
                      },
```

The problem is the function is executed as soon as the dialogue box is opened, before the user can confirm the action.
How can i get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the action from `_auth.signOut()` to `()=>_auth.signOut()`

```
onTap: ()async{
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => Dialogue(text: 'Are you sure you want to logout?',button: 'Logout',action: ()=>_auth.signOut(),pop:true),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Dialogue` widget you need to change the type of `action` parameter to `Future<dynamic> Function()`. And then pass `_auth.signOut` function to it.

Dialogue Widget

```
class Dialogue extends StateFulWidget {
  Future<dynamic> Function() action;
  //other code
}
```

Pass the signOut function to it

```
onTap: ()async{
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => Dialogue(text: 'Are you sure you want to logout?', button: 'Logout', action: _auth.signOut, pop:true),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This returns a type error but thanks for the effort .

Comment: @Bright Strange. What is the error? I see your problem is solved, but I'm just curious as to why is there the error.

Comment: Here is the error : `The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic> Function()'.` This error dissapears when i remove `Function()` on the type declaration but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: you need to pass `_auth.signOut` without the brackets. You must have passed `_auth.signOut()`. Is it?